# How to set and get id of a view

Tags: java, android

I have 2 queries:

1). I want to display kind of screen lik

```
Heading        ImageButton1 ImageButton2
Value1                      Value2
```

Same way number of records

So i have used absolute layout programmatically instead of using xml, is it advisable or there is some other way?

2). At that time of displaying this view, i have to set unique Id to each record and get Id whenever any of 2 buttons pressed of any record.  Can anyone tel me how is that possible?
Means in short how to set and get id which button of which record is selected??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not use absolute layout, try creating layout in XML file.
- Since your imageButtons and values are dynamic, let's check it out this way......
  Store the values or there corresponding id's in an array, then give each imageButton id in sequence. ex first one id as 0, 2nd one id as 1 and so on......
  add OnClickListeners to these, since you will be creating in loop it will be easy,
  From listener you will be able to get the id of button clicked via v.getId().....
  Get the element from array at that particular position as that of id.... for ex.. if id is 0 get element at 0th loc, if id is 1 get element at 1st position

  If i show by array then,:

  [value1/ id of 1] - imagebutton with id 0 
  [value2/ id of 2] - imagebutton with id 1
  [value3/ id of 3] - imagebutton with id 2
  [value4/ id of 4] - imagebutton with id 2

Hope this helps........

Comment: -First of all thanks for responding, i have used absolute layout just because this is just a record, i explained and i have to place as many records server provides and each will have 2 buttons. I tried through xml but its not getting done.

-I mean to say when each record's button clicked and its id or that record's id can be fetched.

Comment: Hey viv, guess what it works... Thank u very much. Thanks a lot, and is there any way to communicate directly here on stakeoverflow or i can ask question directly to u.

Comment: there is chat over here, but i have never used it..... so you will have to post questions directly here only...........     also if in some way or the other my response helped you, you can also accept it, it will give me some points and help other's also ...             god bless you